# Migrating from suftesi to memoir: parcenter style for sections

Tags: sectioning, memoir, suftesi

I am migrating a document from the `suftesi` class to `memoir` (due to printing size problems). I have only one problem left: I need to replicate the `parcenter` style of `suftesi` for the sections, possibly without having to load the `titlesec` package (seems like overkill to me). Also, I use LuaLaTeX, so XeLaTeX specific solutions have to be ruled out.

It may also be helpful to know that I have modified the "standard" sectioning to always increment the section number (even for starred commands) but without printing the section name in the starred version (the opposite of the normal starred command). I included this code also.

So here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,showtrims, twoside, italian, openright,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\let\@nt@ni\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \refstepcounter{section}%
        \@nt@ni*{\thesection}
    }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        \@nt@ni[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
        \@nt@ni{#3}}}%  
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\section{Text}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

here is the result (please do not mind the fonts):

[image]

here is the target result, obtained with `\documentclass[documentstructure=book,secstyle=parcenter,style=smallcaps8]{suftesi}` (please do not mind the fonts or the text but the format only)

[image]

*EDIT* to summarise I want: small caps section titles, centered but one line *below* the section number.

Comment: so allcaps rather than caps and small caps and a line break after the number?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need only the line break after the number. Those are smallcaps too in `suftesi` they are somewhat bigger than the normal text size, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,showtrims, twoside, italian, openright,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\memoirsection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#4}O{#4}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
     \refstepcounter{section}%
     \memoirsection*{\thesection}%
  }{%
    \memoirsection[#2][#3]{#4}%
   }%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\twolinecenter}
\setsecindent{0pt}
\setsechook{%
  \setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\par}%
  \sethangfrom{\noindent##1}%
}
\newcommand{\twolinecenter}[1]{%
  \hbox{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\scshape\centering#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{a}
\section{Text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, contrary to what the documentation of `memoir` seems to suggest, `\setsecnumformat` and `\sethangfrom` declarations in a hook ***aren't*** local to the stated sectional level, but will affect all other sectional levels. This is the reason for `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in the redefinition of `\section`, that I made compatible with the two optional arguments of `memoir`.

Comment: yes I wondered whether the global nature of the redeclaration was desired. We'll see...

Comment: Ok, this wins because of the explanation of the locality and globality of changes

Comment: I'm not sure if is a bug that  the changes affect also lower levels. It looks more as if enables "inheritance". You can always undo the definition by setting the lower level hook.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It also affects upper levels. Once you do `\setsecnumformat{whatever}` in the hook, this changes the definition of `\@seccntformat`.

Comment: I can't see this, if I use e.g. `\setsubsechook` to add red color to the number it affects only subsection and subsubsection but not chapter and section.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See example in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37554962#37554962

Answer (score 2):

[image]

seems like in memoir you just need

```
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname}
\sethangfrom{#1\par}
```

full document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,showtrims, twoside, italian, openright,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\let\@nt@ni\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \refstepcounter{section}%
        \@nt@ni*{\thesection}
    }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        \@nt@ni[#2]{#3}%
    }{%
        \@nt@ni{#3}}}%  
}

\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname}
\sethangfrom{#1\par}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\section{Text}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would ask you how this works, but being `memoir` I know that some deep magic is involved. Obviously it works

Comment: well not very deep magic normally latexs section head internals invokes `\@hangfrom` which makes a hanging paragraph hanging from the section number so in article you'd have a big `\makeatletter` block redefining internals but i noticed that memoir has a specific command that (just) redefined `\@hangfrom` so here I make it do `\par` so you get the number a paragraph break then the title